# Application crashing due to java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError No Implementation Found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using external .so library files for my application. Upon trying to use them in my app, it started crashing for a function that is called in the code.[Error pulled from crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFKU5.png):

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError No Implementation Found

Any assistance would be appreciated. I am running out of things to test with the code. My assumption of the issue is that it is not actually loading the library which to me would explain why no implementation could be found. I do call the function to load the library here. [Code that is loading the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXPGm.png)